# Is Vishvaksena mentioned in any major scriptures?

Tags: vishwaksena

By major, I mean Vedas and related Shruti, Upanishads, the two epics, and Mahapuranas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Vishvakshena is mentioned in some Puranas aa given below:

[Shrimad Bhagavata, Canto 12, Chapter 11, Verse 20](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-bhagavata-purana/d/doc216706.html)

> 20. The goddess of fortune, Sri, who never leaves the Lord’s side, appears with Him in this world as the representation of His internal potency. Visvaksena, the chief among His personal associates, is known to be the personification of the Pancaratra and other tantras. And the Lord’s eight doorkeepers, headed by Nanda, are His mystic perfections, beginning with anima.

[Garuda Purana, Brihaspati Sanhita: Chapter 126](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-garuda-purana-dutt/d/doc122606.html)

> Then having worshipped the deities, beauty, growth and Garuda, he should worship the guardian deities of the different quarters of the heaven and the god Brahma, above, and the god Ananta, below. After that, the god Vishvaksena should be worshipped at the north-east angle of the Mandalam.

[Devi Bhagavata Purana, Book 8, Chapter 14](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/devi-bhagavata-purana/d/doc57302.html)

> He manifesting His Śuddha Sattva and super-extraordinary powers, and united with Aṇimā, Laghimā, etc., the eight Siddhis, is reigning there surrounded by His Pāriśadas Viṣvaksena and others. He is the one God of all; He is without a second. For the welfare of all, He is holding Sudarśana and His various other weapons; and the powers of His arms are great.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, Vishvaksena is mentioned as one of the names of Vishnu in the Mahabharata Vishnu sahasra nAma (1000 names of Vishnu)

> sarvagah sarva vid bhAnur vishwakseno janArdhanaH | 
>   vedo vedavidhavyango vedAngo vedavith kaviH ||

Edit: According to Sri Shankara, Vishnu is called Vishvaksena because he routs the armies of the daityas on all sides.

Translation:
123 सर्वगः  sarvagah    All-pervading
124 सर्वविद्भानुः   sarvavid-bhaanuh    All-knowing and effulgent
125 विष्वक्सेनः vishvaksenah    He against whom no army can stand
126 जनार्दनः    janaardanah He who gives joy to good people
127 वेदः    vedah   He who is the Vedas
128 वेदविद् vedavid The knower of the Vedas
129 अव्यंगः avyangah    Without imperfections
130 वेदांगः vedaangah   He whose limbs are the Vedas
131 वेदविद् vedavit He who contemplates upon the Vedas
132 कविः    kavih   The seer

Comment: Great find @Lazy Lubber

Comment: Please add translation also.

Comment: @SK I thought you wanted major scripture and not Vishnu Sahasranama?

Comment: @Ikshvaku He mentioned epics in the list of scriptures. Vishnu sahasranama is from Mahabharata.

Comment: @LazyLubber Oh that's right.

Comment: @Krishna Translation depends on the school of philosophy. Two commentaries that I know of are available. One supposedly by Sri Shankara (dont know if it is Adi Shankara) and other by Sri Parashara Bhatta. Each commentator sometimes gives different meanings for same name, so providing a translation is tricky. Please refer to the commentaries.

Comment: Then add the translation which converges with question and mention the translator name.

Comment: Added the meaning of the name Vishvaksena, according to Sri Shankara.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I meant translation of the verse.

Comment: Ok, this is also done. But commentary is not given by me.